# Windows 8: Share "Something went wrong Couldn't share Document with SkyDrive" error message

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

By my application am creating a pdf file & sharing it via `Share Charm`. In most times i could successfully sharing the document to `Sky Drive, Mail` etc..
But at rarely when i sharing the same document am getting an error message like 
  "`Something went wrong Couldn't share Document with SkyDrive`"
 
 
& after that i couldn't share that document.
  I want to know about at whatever conditions this error may occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a working solution to this problem

See this links

[How to share a file that has been created on the fly](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5cedecdc-b106-4b01-ba97-d89eef7e5621/how-to-share-a-file-that-has-been-created-on-the-fly?forum=winappswithcsharp)

[Share Contract Closes Immediately](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/40a53a58-57e1-43da-ada9-dc58346692e1/share-contract-closes-immediately?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Answer (score 1):

If its a generic message such as: Something went wrong with Share. Try again later - when you run the app from VS, then this might help [(from here- images)](http://irisclasson.com/2013/02/18/error-windows-8-visual-studio-2012-something-went-wrong-with-share-try-again-later/):

Open Task Manager, end the explorer.exe task (Details tab).
Select Run new task from File in Task Manager and type in explorer in the textbox and click OK.

If it is specific to Sky Drive then it is likely that it has something to do with the Sky Drive application and not your app. I'm unable to replicate the problem you are having.

I would try to isolate the error and see exactly what triggers the error.

Start with debugging the share charm, but keep in mind that if you end the debug session in the datarequest handler the charm might break and stop working, and you will need to apply the dirty fix I wrote above.

Output what happens to a file and run the share until you get the problem, and see if there is anything in the file that can help you figure out the problem.

Also, check the event log on you computer for a hint, I tend to use powershell for those things, open powershell in admin mode and run **Get-EventLog Application -newest 10 | Format-List** . Otherwise type Event Viewer while in the 'Metro' mode and look under Applications.

[From MSDN- on common issues with the Share](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465251.aspx)

> Common issues
>   Unhandled exceptions in a target app cause it to immediately terminate and be replaced with an error message. The target app should gracefully handle any expected errors originating from the user, such as invalid input data, and report them to the user.
>   If a target app takes too long to respond to an activation event, the system assumes that the app is choosing not to respond and displays an error. Processing data should be moved out of the activation handler whenever possible, typically by storing a ShareOperation object and processing it asynchronously.
>   Calls to sharing the API can throw exceptions when called too many times or in the wrong order. When you implement a long-running share, be sure to call the share methods in the following order, without calling any single method twice in a row.
>   ReportStarted
>   ReportDataRetrieved
>   ReportSubmittedBackgroundTask
>   You can call ReportError or ReportCompleted at any time to complete the sharing operation.
>   To learn more about the share API, see Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.ShareTarget namespace.

Comment: yea am getting an event log saying that "LiveComm (13544) C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Packages\microsoft.microsoftskydrive_8weky b3d8bbwe\LocalState\LiveComm\bfd5bed4ff15b1d4\120712-0049\: An attempt to open the file "C:\Users\ xxx.SYS\AppData\Local\Packages\microsoft.microsoftskydrive_8wekyb3d8bbwe‌​\LocalState\LiveCo mm\bfd5bed4ff15b1d4\120712-0049\DBStore\LogFiles\edb.log" for read only access failed with system error 32 (0x00000020): "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. ". The open file operation will fail with error -1032 (0xfffffbf8)."